# "I have problems with someone" translation

Tags: translation

How to translate this:

"I have problems with someone."

for example if am in basketball team and am talking with someone so i tell him :

I have problems with my basketball team

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try:

- ～とうまくいかない (not get along or have problems with ～)